# AngularJS- Autofill Dropdown with Information from Previous Page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have searched quite throughly on StackOverFlow, but did not find my answer, so I will ask below.

I have a form with a dropdown menu. And if the user clicks a button, it will take it to a new html page with more information to fill out. But how do I pass my data from the dropdown menu to the next page and autofill the same dropdown menu with the option selected if I am using the same controller for the form for both pages?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

var currentEquipmentType = "";

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.addEquipment.type = "";
  $scope.addEquipment.name = "";
  
  $scope.typeList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
  
  //trying to get this info passed onto the next page.
  if (sessionStorage.type) {
    currentEquipmentType = sessionStorage.type;
  }
  
  $scope.getEquipmentInfo = function() {
    if ($scope.addEquipment.name !== undefined) {
      sessionStorage.name = $scope.addEquipment.name;
      sessionStorage.type = $scope.addEquipment.type;
    
    } else {
      // warning message
    }
  }

}]);
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="addEquiment.name">

<select ng-model="addEquipment.type" ng-options="type for type in typeList">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Please select a type.</option>
</select>
```

```html
<!-- on the next page (different html file, but uses the same controller as the previous page) -->

<!-- more form inputs here -->

<select ng-model="addEquipment.type" ng-options="type for type in typeList">
  <option>NEED THE OPTION SELECTED FROM PREVIOUS PAGE</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can good use directive and set the same template for both dropdowns like in example, every element has attribute `select-box` will filled this template:

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive("selectBox", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template :'<select ng-model="addEquipment" ng-options="type for type in typeList"><option value="">Please select a type.</option></select>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.typeList = ['A','B','C','D'];
      }
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" >
  <div select-box></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This definitely does make the code a lot cleaner, but my question is still unanswered. Say, my select box is in index.html and nextPg.html. index.html also has a button that takes one to nextPg.html. If I choose "B" in index.html, how do I make "B" persistent in nextPg.html?

Comment: Put this directive in your main.js  where your app is, and use it global in all pages. Use only `<div select-box></div>`

Comment: it work when you put this directive in a global js file where your app is

Comment: Well, I currently have just one js file called "app.js" where I defined the app. I put the directive there and select-box directive definitely appears, but the data isn't passed.

Comment: can I see your app file, how you use it?

Comment: Honestly, what I had above was all as of now using sessionStorage (commented out after your response). I know I can just use ng-show  to display certain input fields based on the select box option on the same page, but I'm really curious to know how to pass what I have chosen on the select box and keep that selection on a different page.

Comment: Yeh to save what you selected you must use sessionStorage or localStorage

Answer (score 0):

**SERVICES SOLUTION:**

One way to persist data in AngularJS apps would be in Services (or Factories). Services are singletons so they will persist data as long as you don't refresh the page.

```
app.service('YourService', function() {
    let yourDataFromPreviousPage = {
      page: 1,
      // currentEquipmentType: '',
      // properties can be added later from controllers when you have them resolved.
    };

    function yourData() {
       return ['A','B','C','D'];
    }

    angular.extend(this,{
       yourData,
       yourDataFromPreviousPage
    });

});
```

Then just inject the service in your directive, and you can get/set variables on service from there.

More info about services:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Really good comparison between services and factories:

https://toddmotto.com/factory-versus-service

**UI-ROUTER SOLUTION**

Another way would be to use ui-router to keep track of your routes through states - I would recommend this approach since it's de-facto standard nowdays for SPA applications. You can set up routes for different pages and when you switch to different page-state you load different parameters.

You can pass objects between states using:

```
$state.go('yourstate', { 
  // your object properties
});
```

For more info about ui-router:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference

**LOCAL STORAGE**

You got that covered in previous comments.